# How to get Facebook test user email and password after create?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, integration-testing, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium to test a Facebook auth app. Currently I am using a script in the test suite to create Facebook test users by posting to the test user api found here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/

```
https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/accounts/test-users?
installed=true
&name=FULL_NAME
&locale=en_US
&permissions=read_stream
&method=post
&access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

This gives me back a response of:

```
{ 
  "id": "1234...",  
  "access_token":"1234567..." , 
  "login_url":"https://www.facebook.com/platform/test_account..."
  "email": "example...@tfbnw.net",
  "password": "1234..."
}
```

This gives me the username and password of the test. However If I want to reuse the user in a later test I don't know how to get this info. I might be over looking something. If I do a GET request to get a list of registered test users the response looks like this:

```
{
 "data" [
   { 
    "id": "1231....",  
    "access_token":"1223134..." , 
    "login_url":"https://www.facebook.com/platform/test_account.." 
   }
   { 
    "id": "1231....",  
    "access_token":"1223134..." , 
    "login_url":"https://www.facebook.com/platform/test_account.." 
   }
 ]
}
```

This response dosen't give me any emails/passwords which I'd need to login the test users in a full test. I'd rather not log them in by using the `access_token` and `login_url` because this isn't true to the Facebook auth flow on the site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/#changepw

Facebook does not store cleartext passwords and will only return the password on user creation per the documentation. You can change the user's password to anything at any time without knowing their password so you could set all your test users to have whatever password you want after creation and just rely on that when running your tests.

Comment: How about the email? how do you get that?

Comment: @KenStruys it was a while ago but did you find how to get the email with test users? I cannot get them and no error regarding permissions appear when I try to

Comment: If you use the newest graph api you can get the email no problem https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/app/accounts/test-users

Comment: this is where you want to get from the above link: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<app-id>/roles/test-users/ .. thanks!

Comment: I batch created 2 test users right now and the password wasn't shown, I had to edit one by one and assign a new one each.